# SyncAdapter stopped syncing

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

Our implementation of SyncAdapter is not syncing with android version 4.4.4. Works well with lower API devices.

Our app uses an [AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html) to communicate with the server. I've tested it with many different devices and models, running android from API level 10 onwards. We recently acquired two Android 4.4.4 based devices (Moto E, Nexus 5) and started having trouble with the SyncAdapter. Here's the xml config:

```
<sync-adapter 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="our.provider"
    android:accountType="our.authenticator"
    android:userVisible="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    android:supportsUploading="true" />
```

Even if I put the manual and expedited flags the sync doesn't trigger:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(SyncAdapter.dummyAccount(context), SYNC_PROVIDER, bundle);
```

I'm trying this over WiFi and with the power cord connected to dismiss any power usage-related optimisations. The target SDK is set to the latest version:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

And I have [all the necessary permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#DeclareSyncAdapterManifest):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

There's one thing that strikes me as unusual. The devices report API level = 19, but the SDK says API 19 is equivalent to android 4.4.**2**, instead of android 4.4.4:

[image: Android 4.4.2 = API level 19]

Could this be related to this issue?

Sorry for not being more helpful or descriptive, but I'm truly out of clues on how to proceed debugging this issue. Thanks in advance.

### Edit

Further thoughts:

- Seems to be related to the exponential backoff algorithm that is used when a sync fails. I ended up canceling the request before starting a new one and using a manual sync (ignores backoff). I know this is not ideal, but in my use case the user expects data to be synced inmediately. Make sure to give SyncManager a look: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java
- Uninstalling the app and running it again solves the issue, so it might be related to the account's permissions. Note that I did remove some unused services from the manifest, but nothing related to the SyncAdapter or its associated classes.
- [Seems that I'm not alone on this one](http://www.kylook.com/en/questions/?question=8427).

Comment: Api level 19 is Android 4.4 and all other sub-versions, like 4.4.4 and 4.4.2. See the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html.
You're not actually telling us what's happening or not happening on devices with Android 4.4.4 installed. Can you see the device "hitting" your server at all?
Also, changing the `AndroidManifest.xml` without changing the version-code could create issues. What happens if you revert the changes in the manifest file? Will the sync run on the Android 4.4.4 devices now?

Comment: Can you drive this reliably?  I cannot repro the problem on a 4.4.4 Nexus 5.

Comment: I've modded this app (https://github.com/bmeike/MiniSync) to match your description as nearly as I can.  Both forced and scheduled syncs are working on my Nexus.  Not saying it can't happen.  Just saying I can't see it, yet.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike gave you the answer.  Nexus 5 is smartPhone enough to know when to sync.

Comment: How are you verifying the SyncAdapter is being call on < API19 and not called on API19?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Your example looks great, most things look much simpler. Don't you need to do something on the `AccountAuthenticator` bind? BTW, no, I can't reproduce it reliably.

Comment: @Darwind, @PrplRugby I'm logging first thing on `onPerformSync`. I'm monitoring the http requests with mitmproxy and looking at the log of a local instance of the web app. No hits on the server. Good catch on the manifest modifications, I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: @jlhonora The system only requests the `AccountAuthenticator` in response to the various `*getAuthToken*` methods.  In that minimal example, I never do that.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Perfect. I made some changes based on your example and it seems to be working fine (can't see the error yet either). If you like, include your comment as an answer and I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: @jlhonora would like to know the status of the issue. Is it resolved for permanently? I am also facing the same issue on 4.4.4 randomly. Do you have any suggestions.

Comment: @ArunAntoney still happens randomly. We're planning on moving away from sync adapter. We don't really leverage its capabilities, and a background service does the trick for our usage.

Comment: @jlhonora thanks for your quick replay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not an answer, [this](http://github.com/bmeike/MiniSync) may help.  It is, to the best of my knowledge, a completely minimal SyncAdapter.

The example does *not* have an AccountAuthenticator component.  The AccountAuthenticator is required only if there are calls to one of the *getAuthToken* methods.

As noted in the comments, I tried to duplicate your issue, using this minimal example, and could not do so.  Perhaps you can start with it and build to something that fails.